# Error using cedilla (ç) in affiliation line with elsarticle class

Tags: accents, elsarticle

I'm using the [`elsarticle`](https://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle) class to typeset my paper for submission. However, I can't use the c-cedilla character (`ç`), nor the cedilla macro (`\c{c}`), in the `\affiliation` command. In the body of the text, it works without problem. I suspected it could be due to a local redefinition of the `\c` macro, but I couldn't find anything on that matter in the class' source code.

Here is my MCVE. If I remove the `ç` from the `organization` key, it compiles.

```latex
\documentclass[preprint]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
    \author[1]{João da Silva}
    \affiliation[1]{organization={Inovação}, addressline={Address}, city={Some place}, postcode={00000}, country={Somewhere}}
\end{frontmatter}
Inovação
\end{document}
```

And here is the relevant part of the log:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \elsaddress.
<to be read again> 
                   \crcr 
l.6 ...ce}, postcode={00000}, country={Somewhere}}
```

Comment: it works with \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}.

Comment: but it is a bug in the class. With `\csxappto{elsaddress}{` it basically does an \xdef on the value, and this can easily break.

Comment: Unfortunately, the class uses pseudo-expl3 code without adhering to the conventions and the code is ***very*** buggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ulrike Fischer pointed out, I solved the problem using `fontenc`. The following works as expected.

```latex
\documentclass[preprint]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
    \author[1]{João da Silva}
    \affiliation[1]{organization={Inovação}, addressline={Address}, city={Some place}, postcode={00000}, country={Somewhere}}
\end{frontmatter}
Inovação
\end{document}
```